# Where should we release our video dataset for activity recognition?

Tags: dataset, image-classification, activity-recognition

We have an activity recognition dataset made of tens of thousands video clips.

Which are the alternatives to release it to the research community?

Is there any public website? 
I saw for instance that mendeley has a datasetweb site.

Comment: How big is your dataset in terms of number of videos, video length, and total memory size of all the videos combined?

Comment: around 20k videos for a total of 10-20 GB of mp4 data.